# Is ML.net same to Tensorflow.NET?

Tags: tensorflow, ml.net

I downloaded a Tensorflow saved model and want to get data from it.
**Can I use ML.NET?**
I do not know python I have to use .net to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to leverage ONNX.  ONNX (www.onnx.ai) is an open-source format for Machine Learning.  You can use the ONNX transformers for the appropriate in->out framework here:
https://github.com/onnx/onnx

You can translate a Tensorflow model into ONNX and ML.NET support ONNX inference.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that it is doable, running the tensorflow trained model in ML.Net.
[ML.Net documentation on using tensorflow model](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/run-with-ml-net-c-code-a-tensorflow-model-exported-from-azure-cognitive-services-custom-vision/).

Update: 
<strike>The catch is you will need to have tensorflow frozen model in place of tensorflow saved model. For understanding the difference between these models you can refer this [link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33975/what-is-the-difference-between-tensorflow-saved-model-pb-and-frozen-inference-gr)</strike>

There is a tutorial that provides an explanation on how to use tensorflow saved model in ML.NET here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/text-classification-tf)

Comment: So if I do not have frozened model I have to use Tensorflow.net?

Comment: There is actually no tensorflow.net, it is just tensorflow. You can follow the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/text-classification-tf In this tutorial they have used tensorflow saved model. You can try this tutorial and check it out.